# Zoom out with preserve aspect ratio

Tags: imagemagick

Need to zoom out image adding white border, but preserving aspect ratio od image. How to do that in ImageMagick ? I've tried adding border with parameters `-bordercolor White -border 100x100 image.jpg` but this changes aspect ratio of image (width px / height px changed, but need preseve it).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add the white border and preserve the aspect ratio, you can use this commands:

```
newsize=$(identify -format "%[fx:w+100]x%[fx:h+100]" rose:)
convert rose: \( -clone 0 -resize "$newsize" -fx "white" \) \
    -reverse -gravity Center -composite newrose.png
```

The program uses two images, as a list or a stack:

`rose:` is the first image;

`\( -clone 0 -resize "$newsize" -fx "white" \)` is the second image;

`-clone 0` makes a copy of the first image;

`-resize "$newsize"` resizes it to the desired size;

`-fx "white"` fills the whole second image by the color white;

`-reverse` swaps the images;

`-gravity Center` aligns the images by the center;

`-composite` overlaps the images.

> `rose:`
>
> [image: rose:] (70x46)
>
> `\( -clone 0 -resize "$newsize" -fx "white" \)`
>
> [image: background] (170x112)
>
> `newrose.png`
>
> [image: newrose.png] (170x112)

```
70 / 46 = 1.5217
170 / 112 = 1.5178
```